# Websecurity Create User And Account. The Provider encountered an unknown error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net MVC membership functionality for creating user. I have created 2 database which has same version one is for live and one is for testing. User creation is suddenly failed.

My Membership Tables are
- UserProfile
- UserInRoles
- webpages_Membership

I a using WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount method. Its working fine earlier in both database.

After few days there is no change in both database my test database failed to create user.

Problem is insert webpages_Membership record only other tables UserProfile, UserInRoles record inserted. I am unable to debug where is the problem. The only exception is raised **"The Provider encountered an unknown error"**. How to detect where is the problem in last table. Live database is working fine, problem in testing.

Comment: Try checking your connection string to the database

Comment: Connection is working fine, I already mentioned, record insert in UserProfile table but not insert in webpages_Membership table. That is the main issue, I am unable to track where is the issue.